# Javascript InvalidCharacterError when modifying a css name with a space

Tags: javascript, css, dom

I'm modifying some buttons that are dynamically generated through JavaScript. I have no control over statically declaring the class names which is why I've written a function to do it for me on page load. I understand why it's happening (it doesn't like the space in 'zocial button'), I just need a fix and I'm definitely not that gifted with JavaScript. Here's the error if you inspect the button on the page:
Unncaught InvalidCharacterError: Failed to execute 'add' on 'DOMTokenList': The token provided ('zocial facebook') contains HTML space characters, which are not valid in tokens.
Here's my javascript code:

```
var buttonz = document.getElementsByName('provider');
for (var i = 0, length = buttonz.length; i < length; i++) {
    if (buttonz[i].value == 'Facebook')
    {
        buttonz[i].classList.remove('btn-default');
        buttonz[i].classList.add('zocial button');
    }
```

If you want to see it live here you go:
http://jsbin.com/nifuxoyo/1/watch

Comment: Classes can't have spaces in HTML. Please try to add 'zocial' and 'button' separately or use a '-' (dash?).

Answer (score 73, accepted):

Well, class names cannot contain spaces, because the space *separates* multiple class names from each other. For example, if your HTML contains

```
class="zocial button"
```

it means that this element has **two** classes, "zocial" and "button".

If you want to add both of these classes, you have to pass each one as argument to the method:

```
buttonz[i].classList.add('zocial', 'button');
```

More information can be found in the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.classList).

Comment: thanks man... its simple when u know it ;)